# App to undelete all images and movies, on Android

Tags: android

Any such app?

Paid is okay but preferably free.

I know many free aps. But they ask to watch ads for every picture.

After that they fail to undelete

Comment: What Android version? Is your phone rooted?

Comment: Phone not rooted. POCO xiaomi. Latest version

Comment: recent Android versions use File based Encryption (FBE) which means that every file is encrypted individually. Therefore recovering the file data is useless unless you also get the necessary keys (master key + file specific inodes that contain the filse-specific key data). I am not aware of a product that can do this all.